# can i import csv with real password to firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I want to add multiple users with pre define paswword to Firebase Authentication project

I know it can be done using Hash password but in my case i have the real password not the generated hash password

can i user `firebase auth:import` to upload using realpassword or are there any way to convert real password to hash password using my project hash parameters ??

for example

[image: sample of userdata.csv]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the below work around

I stored all users data in excel sheet

Then I loop in sheet data and called sign up method for each row

Comment: ca you please give  whole source code how we can read excel and signup whole database to firestore

Answer (score 5):

You can hash with SHA256 and import these users. Here is an example in Node.js using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users):

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
const importOptions = {
  hash: {
    algorithm: 'SHA256',
    rounds: 1,
  },
};
// For every user, you generate the password hash and a salt.
const currentRawSalt = generateRandomSalt();
const computedPasswordHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(currentRawSalt + yourUserPlainPassword).digest();
importUserRecord = {
  uid: yourUserUid,
  email: youUserEmail,
  passwordSalt: Buffer.from(currentRawSalt),
  passwordHash: computedPasswordHash,
};
admin.auth().importUsers([importUserRecord], importOptions)
  .then((result) => {
    // Check result to confirm success.
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to import with a plain text password. You will have to generate the password hash to import them. There are a lot of hashing options, all described in the documentation on [importing users with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users).

Comment: Is there any way to convert plain text to hash using project hash parameters

Comment: All the hashing options are explained in the docs I linked. As that page also explains "On successful sign-in, Firebase re-hashes the user's password with the internal Firebase hashing algorithm", so your data is merely the initial hashing value to allow the user to sign in to Firebase for the first time. After that Firebase will use its own hashing algorithm.