# Loop user registration for firebase

Tags: firebase, registration, bulk

Could someone please suggest how to properly set up a loop for registration? The idea is that I have an excel file with 500+ users ( emails and raw passwords ) which I wanted to register. As I understood the best thing is to read the excel file in js , assign for each email and password a variable and call the createusernamendpassword method in firebase upon each iteration ? Please don’t suggest using the auth:import as it suggest you to have already salted and hashed passwords ( as I don’t have them ). The whole point is to create in bulk absolutely new usernames

Answer (score 0):

If you do this with the regular client-side SDKs, you will quickly be rate-limited as quickly creating accounts from a single client is a common abuse scenario.

The Firebase Admin SDKs are designed to (only) run in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. And these Admin SDKs have dedicated APIs to [bulk import users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users). That is the best way to go about this.

You can also [use the Firebase CLI to but import the users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-import), which is quite similar.

Neither of these options takes a so-called cleartext password though, so you'll want to hash those first as shown on bojeil's answer here: [can i import csv with real password to firebase authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121457/can-i-import-csv-with-real-password-to-firebase-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Adkin SDK from your local machine or a trusted environment like a server or cloud functions, You can run the `Create User` from the auth package inside a loop. it is important to implement tracking if you are doing it in Firebase Cloud Functions as the 9-minute timeout (if configured) might not be enough to finalize processing.

```js
async function ProcessUsers(){
for(const user in userList){
await admin
  .auth()
  .createUser({
    email: 'user@example.com',
    emailVerified: false,
    password: 'secretPassword'
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
}
}
```

you can do several improvements from the base script such as setting up a queue to ensure the values are processed before batching more together. But this is sufficient to get started.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user